# How to click on link element with specific text using watir?

Tags: text, click, watir

I'm not able to click on text link 'Add' using **watir**:

PAGE:

```
<div id="divAdd" style="float: right">
    <a onclick="SwitchView('2')" style="color: #1B56A7; cursor: pointer;">Add</a>
</div>
```

Watir CODE:

```
browser.link(:text =>"Add").click
```

EXCEPTION:

```
Unable to locate element, using {:tag_name=>["a"], :text=>"Add"}
```

Please help me how to handle this?

Comment: Without the page, it is hard to be sure why it is happening. My guess would either be the element has not finished loading into the page or is in a frame. I summarized the couple of issues I know of and how to address them on my [blog](http://jkotests.wordpress.com/unable-to-locate-element/)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If the page has a lot of ajax and javascript going on, you may just have to wait a little bit for the client side code to finish rendering the page after it has been loaded from the browser.

Try this

```
browser.link(:text =>"Add").when_present.click
```

If that does not work, then make sure the item is not in a frame or something..

btw, if there is more than one link on the page with the text 'Add' then you may have to specify a container outside the link that lets you identify which link you want.  eg.

```
browser.div(id: => "divAdd").link.when_present.click
```

If

Comment: I had to add `require 'watir-webdriver/locators'`. without it I had an error `NameError: uninitialized constant Watir::Locators`

Comment: That seems strange, what version of Watir are you using?  (might be something related to most recent versions, I've never needed to add that require)

Comment: right, the reason was in watir version. I don't know why but the installation from scratch gave me the old version.

Comment: FYI, this is now deprecated and the correct way to do it is `.wait_until( &:present? )`.

Answer (score 1):

This would be my way of doing it.

```
while browser.div(:class, 'containerDIV').a(:text, 'Add').exists? do
    browser.div(:class, 'containerDIV').a(:text, 'Add').click 
 end
```

Comment: That would continue to click it after the first click.  On my workstation, that would mean 9 times a second.